# Pagination over join table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server request with several tables, for example:

Workorder
WorkorderOccurrence
Schedule

A workorder occurrence is a realisation of a specific schedled workorder
For workorder 1 scheduled every day I have:
Workorder occurrence 1_1 the first day
Workorder occurrence 1_2 the second day

For a workorder 2 scheduled every week I have:
Workorder occurrence 1_7
Workorder occurrence 2_1
Workorder occurence 1_8
And so ...

I have a pagination on the front for an agenda view, but the pagination must be done on workorder and not on the occurrence.
Consequently I would like to return the workorder occurrences (maybe 50, 100, 200,).
but on the 20 workorder request by the pagination. But it seems to eeturn the 20 workorder occurrence with the offset and I don't know how to do this.

Below my attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FctGetWorkorderAgenda]
(
    @SeverityIDsFilter NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @Culture NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'FR-fr',
    @StartDate      DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
    @EndDate        DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
    @PageNumber INT = 0,
    @ResultByPage INT = 50
)
RETURNS @resTable TABLE   
(  
    [WorkorderID] INT NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] DATETIMEOFFSET(0),  
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX),  
    [FixedNextDate] DATETIMEOFFSET(0),
    [NextDate] DATETIMEOFFSET(0),
    [WorkorderStatutType] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [FrequenceType] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [DayOfWeek] INT,
    [DayOfMonth] INT,
    [MonthType] INT,
    [DayOfMonthType] INT,
    [FrequencyTime] TIME(7) NOT NULL,
    [FrequencyOffset] INT, 
    [VendorName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationID] INT NOT NULL,
    [WorkorderSeverity] INT NOT NULL,
    [FullCount] INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @resTableBooking (
    WO.WorkorderID, 
    WO.EndDate, 
    WO.Name, 
    WOO.FixedNextDate, 
    WOO.NextDate, 
    WOO.WorkorderStatutType, 
    S.FrequenceType, 
    S.DayOfWeek, 
    S.DayOfMonth, 
    S.MonthType, 
    S.DayOfMonthType, 
    [FrequencyTime], 
    S.FrequencyOffset, 
    [EquipmentName], 
    [WorkorderSeverity],
    [FullCount])

SELECT 
    WorkorderID, 
    EndDate, 
    Name, 
    FixedNextDate, 
    NextDate, 
    WorkorderStatutType, 
    FrequenceType, 
    DayOfWeek, 
    DayOfMonth, 
    MonthType, 
    DayOfMonthType, 
    FrequencyTime, 
    FrequencyOffset, 
    EquipmentName,
    WorkorderSeverity,
    FullCount
FROM (                  
    SELECT 
    WO.WorkorderID, 
    WO.EndDate, 
    WO.Name, 
    WOO.FixedNextDate, 
    WOO.NextDate, 
    WOO.WorkorderStatutType, 
    S.FrequenceType, 
    S.DayOfWeek, 
    S.DayOfMonth, 
    S.MonthType, 
    S.DayOfMonthType, 
    S.Time AS FrequencyTime, 
    S.FrequencyOffset, 
    E.Name AS EquipmentName,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN (WO.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND (WO.EndDate <= WO.CreatedDate OR WO.NextDate >= WO.EndDate))
                THEN -5 -- WorkorderSeverity.Closed
            WHEN (WO.NextDate <= WO.CreatedDate)
                THEN -4 -- WorkorderSeverity.DeadlineLate
            WHEN (S.FrequenceType = 3) -- FrequencyType.EveryMonth
                THEN IIF(
                DATEADD(day, -7, WO.NextDate) <= WO.CreatedDate, 
                -3 /* WorkorderSeverity.DeadlineWarning */,
                -2 /* WorkorderSeverity.InTime */
                )
            WHEN (S.FrequenceType = 1 OR S.FrequenceType = 6) 
                THEN IIF(
                DATEADD(month, -1, WO.NextDate) <= WO.CreatedDate, 
                -3 /* WorkorderSeverity.DeadlineWarning */,
                -2 /* WorkorderSeverity.InTime */
                )
            WHEN (S.FrequenceType = 0) -- FrequencyType.None
        THEN CASE 
            WHEN (WO.NextDate <= WO.CreatedDate) THEN -4 /* WorkorderSeverity.DeadlineLate */
                WHEN (DATEADD(day, -3, WO.NextDate) <= WO.CreatedDate) THEN -3
                ELSE -2
            END
        ELSE -2
        END
    ) AS WorkorderSeverity,
    COUNT(WO.WorkorderID) OVER() FullCount
    FROM [dbo].[WorkorderOccurrence] WOO WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN [dbo].[Workorder] WO WITH(NOLOCK) ON WO.WorkorderID = WOO.WorkorderID
    JOIN [dbo].[Schedule] S WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.ScheduleID = WO.WorkorderScheduleID
    JOIN [dbo].[Equipment] E WITH(NOLOCK) ON E.EquipmentID = WO.EquipmentID 
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.Localization l WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.CultureKey = E.CultureKey AND l.CultureName = @culture 

    
    WHERE (WOO.FixedNextDate IS NOT NULL AND WOO.FixedNextDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    OR WOO.NextDate IS NOT NULL AND WOO.NextDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)

    GROUP BY WO.WorkorderID, WO.EndDate, WO.Name, WO.CreatedDate, WO.NextDate,
    WOO.NextDate, WOO.FixedNextDate, WOO.WorkorderOccurrenceID, WOO.WorkorderStatutType,
    S.FrequenceType, S.DayOfWeek, S.DayOfMonth, S.MonthType, S.DayOfMonthType, S.Time, S.FrequencyOffset,  
    E.Name
    ) AS base
    
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  [value] 
        FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@SeverityIDsFilter, ';')
    ) AS DynamicSeverityFilter ON WorkorderSeverity = DynamicSeverityFilter.[value]
    WHERE ((DynamicSeverityFilter.[value] IS NULL AND @SeverityIDsFilter = '') OR DynamicSeverityFilter.[value] IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY base.WorkorderID, base.NextDate
    

    OFFSET (@PageNumber * @ResultByPage) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @ResultByPage ROWS ONLY
    RETURN
    END
```

Comment: As a bit of an FYI, multi-line table value functions (mlTVF) are known to perform (very) poorly. If you are using a TVF then you really should be using an inline TVF, as the performance difference can be quite significant.

Comment: Also, an `nvarchar(MAX)` is a terrible choice of data type for a search column; by using `MAX` you are stating the value is likely to be more than 8,000 bytes in size, and *could* be up to **~2 billion** bytes in size. Doing an equality comparison on such values can be *very* resource intensive, for such large values.

Comment: Also, not to mention: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu thank but isn't the subject here, I search a solution for the moment and what is TVF ?

Comment: I define that in my comment: *"multi-line table value functions (mlTVF)"* The acronym (in brackets) after the phrase denotes that's the acronym for that phrase: mlTVF = **m**ulti-**l**ine **T**able **V**alue **F**unction.

Comment: I would argue that listening to advice about improving your code is on topic and the suggestions from @Larnu are all very valid. Converting this to an inline table valued function would be simple. Just get rid of the table variable and return the select statement.

Comment: For the problem at hand it is totally unclear to me what you are trying to do and what is not working with the code you posted.

Comment: I think he has a head -> rows table, and he wants to paginate X number of heads together with all their rows. But right now, the pagination is on the total row number

Answer (score 0):

I think the "easiest" is to make this a two-step solution.

1. Fetch head data first into a table variable and use the offset thingy.
2. Join the head data with the row data and select "out" it together.

Simplified version of your function (but i also think you should convert it to regular procedure)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FctGetWorkorderAgenda]
(
    @SeverityIDsFilter NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @Culture NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'FR-fr',
    @StartDate      DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
    @EndDate        DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
    @PageNumber INT = 0,
    @ResultByPage INT = 50
)
RETURNS @resTable TABLE   
(  
    [WorkorderID] INT NOT NULL,
   ...
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Get data by filter
    declare @head TABLE (workorderID INT)
    insert into @head (workOrderID)
    select wo.workorderID
    from Workorder wo
    ... needed joins
    where <your filters>
    ORDER BY ...
    OFFSET (@PageNumber * @ResultByPage) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @ResultByPage ROWS ONLY
    
    -- Return joined data to the client
    insert into  @resTableBooking (
    WO.WorkorderID, 
    ...
    )
    SELECT WorkorderID
    ,   ...
    FROM    @head h
    inner join rest...
     ...
     ORDER BY ...

    RETURN
END
```